# What does the existence of a map between function fields $k(Y)\to k(X)$ imply for varieties $X,Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is well known that if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of affine varieties, then the image of $f$ is dense in $Y$ (ie $f$ is dominant) if and only if the homomorphism between coordinate rings, $f^*:K[Y]\to K[X]$, is injective.

Similarly, if $\phi:X\to Y$ is a dominant rational map, then $\phi^*:K[Y]\to K(X)$ is injective and hence can be extended to an (injective) homomorphism $\phi^*:K(Y)\to K(X)$.

However, I have not seen a converse to the latter in my textbook. What I have thought is that if there is a homomorphism between any two function fields, $\phi^*:K(Y)\to K(X)$, it must be injective automatically since they are fields, therefore it is not a matter of "when is it injective?", but rather one of "when does one exist?". However, any such $\phi^*$ clearly restricts to an injective homomorphism $\phi^*:K[Y]\to K[X]$, and we can conclude that $\phi^*$ induces a dominant morphism $\phi:X\to Y$ by the first statement.

My question is: is the last paragraph's argument correct? It seems 'obvious' but I have checked 4 different textbooks and none make any mention of it, so perhaps it is too obvious.

Comment: The injective map $\phi^*:K(Y)\to K(X)$ only restricts to give a map $\phi^*:K[Y]\to K(X)$, not $K[X]$ in general.

Comment: You are right. In fact, $\phi^*$ induces a dominant *rational* map, not a morphism. I guess it wasn't as 'clear' as I claimed it to be.